# ANDROID - creating users/accounts for server/service login privileges

Tags: android, authentication, account, creation

Hello everyone on here,

I have an application I am working on that requires the user to be able to login to an account in order to gain access to privileges and other services they would otherwise be denied. They will be able to use the basic app itself without login or creating an account but in order to talk to the server and have their data stored they will need to create an account.

So far Ive looked for the past couple of days and most threads here or other forums talk mostly about using the google account for doing things which is great for a simple app but the project I am working on is anything but simple :p

So.....can the wonderful people of stack overflow direct me to information regarding the process of creating a user account on the app that would correlate to one on a server that can talk to and login to a service that is hosted on that same server. That would be great....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one: write a web app that manages users and accounts using your favorite server side language/framework.

Step two: Expose some HTTP interface for Android clients (a simple form will probably do).

Step three: Use HttpClient to talk to your webapp. For example, post username, password, user info to the form in step two.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) Ive already gotten the basic way it would work just like you explained. However Im wondering what can I do to ensure that each user creates a unique ID everytime they sign up for a new account. Also do you know of any tutorials that deal with the creating a UID for users signing up for an account

Comment: If you let users select their own ID, just check that if it exists when you register a new user. If it does, return an appropriate error status/message. There are different ways to do this, but usually you will be using a database, so something like `SELECT UID FROM USER WHERE UID='user1'` will do.

Comment: I had a system written out where when a user first creates an account a UID is created and stored on the server but also sent back to the phone and then held in storage on the phone. Then later thats used to auto login the user to their account so they dont have to continue to log into the server manually each time....which would be a pain in the ass. We have some php scripts that would auto generate the UID and send it to the phone but we were concerned about the security of allowing a user to just auto login. What if their phone is lost/stolen.....

Comment: Oh also I want to have the UID sent to the phone upon that devices first communication with the server. Im thinking it would be best to have the UID created on the server so its not dependent on some internal id from the phone itself. That way when the user gets rid of their phone or gives it to some one they can reclaim their account easier since the UID would be generated server side.

Comment: "If your only tool is a hammer, everything starts to look like a nail." This is my response to the "use http". Http has HUGE overhead for what you're doing. The only reason to use it is because "it's all you know." The high-performance solution is also less code and just as easy to do; just make a network connection to a server you write that receives connections on a given port on a given machine...